# React fine-uploader upload the file

Tags: reactjs, fine-uploader

I have a simple react app. I've added `react-fine-uploader` to it. I have a Flask server that accepts files and puts them into MongoDB database. The code for server looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from pymongo import MongoClient
import os
import time
from json import dumps, loads

app = Flask(__name__)


global index
map_dir = 'maps'

client = MongoClient(
    '<connection_string>')

db = client.business


@app.route('/maps', methods=['GET'])
def process():
    cursor = db.maps.find({}, {'_id': False})
    maps = {'maps': []}
    for doc in cursor:
        try:
            maps['maps'].append(doc['filename'])
        except Exception:
            pass
    return dumps(maps)


@app.route('/map/<map_name>', methods=['GET'])
def get_map(map_name):
    doc = db.maps.find_one({'filename': map_name}, {'_id': False})
    return dumps(doc)


@app.route('/uploader', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        parsed = loads(f.read())
        filename = ''.join(f.filename.split('.')[:-1]) + str(index) + '.json'
        parsed['filename'] = filename
        try:
            result = db.maps.insert_one(parsed)
            return 'File uploaded successfully'
        except Exception:
            return 'Error while uploading a file'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    global index
    index = len(os.listdir('maps')) + 1
    app.run(debug=True)
```

It works with standard HTML `input` form with specifying target as `localhost:5000/uploader`. Now I want my `fine-uploader` form to do the same. In code it looks like this:

```
const uploader1 = new FineUploader({
    options: {
        request: {
            endpoint: "localhost:5000/uploader"
        },
        resume: {
            enabled: true
        },
        retry: {
            enableAuto: true,
            showButton: true
        }
    }
});
```

And somewhere in the `render()` method I got: `<Gallery uploader={uploader1} />`

Now I can select file, but when it is selected the form tries to upload it and it fails. Server is running and I can see no request on him in the terminal. Is there something I am doing wrong?

@Edit I've enabled debug mode and it throws something like this into dev console:

`Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https`

Comment: are you hosting your frontend somewhere or just running the page directly on chrome?

Comment: Node.js on localhost